# Batch file only launches one program at a time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to launch SQL Server from a batch file followed by a specific Visual Studio solution.

This is the batch file code:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe -s SBOSQL\SBOINST1 -u sa -p [PASSWORD]

"E:\Projects\comp.sln"

exit
```

When I run the batch file, Windows only launches SQL Server.  When I close SQL Server, it then launches Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to launch a new process and then return immediately:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -s SBOSQL\SBOINST1 -u sa -p [PASSWORD]

start "" "E:\Projects\comp.sln"
```

first argument is the window title (hence the empty string)